# Plugin not working properly

Tags: angular, ionic2

Fail to get the response with file choose, it shows the name of the chosen file but doesn't console and not get the file.

```
this.fileChooser.open().then(uri =>{
 console.log(uri);
});
```

guide me for getting it.

> Ionic -v : 3.19.0, Cordova -v : 8.0.0, node -v : v8.9.0.

help me with this to get the value.

Comment: Did you got any error in `console`?

Comment: No, there is no error. I got everything perfectly, in view but in the console, it shows null. @hrdkisback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to include file chooser in app module

Comment: 'import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';'
everything set up perfectly. @Prosenjit

Answer (score 0):

This plugin only returns file URL. After you get the file URL, use this plugin to get file object https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

Comment: I have used that also, If you cant get any URI from fileChooser than how could you apply that particular value to another object?